# Writing autologin using Net::Http in Ruby

Tags: ruby

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

After reading the doc very carefully, I'm writing the following code snippet for the autologin feature of my program:

```
url = URI.parse('http://localhost/login.aspx')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.basic_auth 'username'
```

The target page asks only the correct user name, no password is needed in order to login, the basic_auth method requires two parameters, user name and password, if I leave one out, I'll get the error, I tried to write it like this "*req.basic_auth 'username*', ''", but I still cannot login.

Could anyone kindly give me a hint?

more info:
I also tried req.basic_auth 'username', '', it didn't seem to be working, I know this because there's another line of line follow right after this one, which is basically doing auto form submission.
    x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("http://localhost/NewTask.aspx"), params)
    puts x.body

And the puts result came back with the redirect to login page body.

Comment: `req.basic_auth 'username', ''` should work.  Maybe it would help if you showed the relevant server log for your application, or any errors ruby is throwing when you run the code?

Comment: Thank you dgtized for your reply. The target site isn't hosted locally, I'm not able to capture the server log, I tried req.basic_auth 'username', '', but it didn't seem to be working, I know it because, there's a auto-submittion code right after this, x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("http://localhost/NewTask.aspx"), params) puts x.body, the put result came back with the redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using [ruby mechanize gem](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). a login example will be much simpler(from official site), for this one, you will not need to do the agent cert and private key thing:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

# create Mechanize instance
agent = Mechanize.new

# set the path of the certificate file
agent.cert = 'example.cer'

# set the path of the private key file
agent.key = 'example.key'

# get the login form & fill it out with the username/password
login_form = agent.get("http://example.com/login_page").form('Login')
login_form.Userid = 'TestUser'
login_form.Password = 'TestPassword'

# submit login form
agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)
```

Comment: Thank you so much c2h2, after digging a bit of mechanize docs, I'm now able to login the site, looks like I'll then rewrite the auto form submission part using mechanize as well.

Comment: don't worry, mark the correct answer and vote if you it worked out for you, and later people come to the same question can refer your selection.